# Create Sql View only a table multiple times

Tags: sql, view

I try create a view with one table multi time here is my code but the result is wrong.Can you help me I cant see here wrong thing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    O1.HomeWorkId, O2.FileInfo AS TeacherFileInfo, 
    O2.Answer AS TeacherAnswer, O1.Answer AS StudentAnswer, 
    O1.StudentId
FROM            
    HomeWorkAnswer AS O1 
INNER JOIN
    HomeWorkAnswer  AS O2 ON O1.FileInfo = O2.FileInfo
WHERE        
    (O1.HomeWorkId > 0)
```

I save my teacher answer and student answer in this table.In my project I select two times for compare the answer.But I thing for performance it is not good and try create something like this.

Comment: You are doing a `SELF JOIN` on the **same** field.

Comment: If you just want to see an exact copy of the table multiple times you could use a `union`.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp
What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: Can you show us `HomeWorkAnswer`? How can you tell which row is a teacher answer vs a student answer? That's what you need to fix in your join

Comment: Yess thank you I never thought Union for solving my problem :) Here is one example I find it now  ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026555/how-to-do-a-union-on-a-single-table

Comment: @SQLChao I have studentId and teacherId field in table ,  If student is giving answer I save teacherId =(-1) , If teacher is giving answer I save studentId= (-1)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using derived tables to separate teachers answer from students answers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sa.HomeWorkId,
  ta.FileInfo AS TeacherFileInfo,
  ta.Answer AS TeacherAnswer,
  sa.Answer AS StudentAnswer,
  sa.StudentID
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM HomeWorkAnswer
    WHERE studentId = -1) ta
JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM HomeWorkAnswer
    WHERE teacherId = -1) sa ON ta.FileInfo = sa.FileInfo
```